# Is is possible to dynamically set paper size before printing in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I use excel 2016, And I have made a Billing and Stock management workbook using VBA. Is there any way to Dynamically set the paper size before printing, I would love to use a TVS MSP 240 classic plus DOT MATRIX printer. Every bill printout is using up an entire page. I have searched he internet for few days now and seem to find no solution. Is there any way stop paper feeding after printing the contents in EXCEL? Can anyone help?

If I use a thermal printer will it solve the problem?

Comment: is it possible to use

         `With Sheets("YOUR_SHEET").PageSetup
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1`